# navbar with submenu width impossible to get right

Tags: html, css

so I have made a navbar with an item that has a submenu.

```
<div id=menu>
  <a href="#"><div class=optie>Nieuws</div></a>
  <a href="#"><div class=optie>Acties</div></a>
  <a href="#"><div class=optie>Over ons</div></a>
  <a href="#"><div class=optie>Webshop</div></a>
  <div class=optie>
    Webshop
    <span class=submenu>
      <a class=suboptie href="#">Producten</a>
      <a class=suboptie href="#">Winkelwagen</a>
      <a class=suboptie href="#">Afrekenen</a>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

The navbar works and it's fine however i can't get the submenu items to have the proper width.

The submenu is nested inside a head which allready has a dynamic size. Since I have to use position absolute it's nearly impossible to calculate the correct width. Is there a way to have the submenu automatically have the same width as the parent?

Here is a jsfiddle.

any help is appreciated

https://jsfiddle.net/eb8k0tbo/3/

Comment: But if your submenu has same width of parent then part of the text might go hidden.

Comment: An image of the intended result might be useful here. Also. there's a reason a `uli/li` structure works so well for these kinds of menus.

Comment: @Paulie_D I just want the submenu to have the same width as the parent it springs from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The need to set `position:relative` on the parent and then `width:100%` on the child.

```css
#menu {
  font-size: 0px;
  width: 80%;
  text-align: center;
}

.optie {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 18px;
  width: calc(20% - 2px);
  height: 1.5em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #919191 0%,#303030 41%,#000000 75%,#000000 100%);
  border: 1px solid grey;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
}

.optie a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.optie:hover a {
  //color: rgb(56,56,56);
}

.optie:hover {
  color: rgb(56,56,56);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fac695 0%,#f4913a 58%,#f4913a 79%,#ed790e 100%);
}

.submenu {
  display: none;
}

.optie:hover .submenu {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 100%;;
}

.suboptie {
  display: block;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #919191 0%,#303030 41%,#000000 75%,#000000 100%);
}
.submenu a:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fac695 0%,#f4913a 58%,#f4913a 79%,#ed790e 100%);
}

.submenu a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.suboptie:hover {
  color: rgb(56,56,56);
}
```

```html
    <div id=menu>
      <a href="#"><div class=optie>Nieuws</div></a>
      <a href="#"><div class=optie>Acties</div></a>
      <a href="#"><div class=optie>Over ons</div></a>
      <div class=optie>
        Webshop
        <span class=submenu>
          <a class=suboptie href="#">Producten</a>
          <a class=suboptie href="#">Winkelwagen</a>
          <a class=suboptie href="#">Afrekenen</a>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
```